# Angular - SmartHTMLElement Web Component issue while rendering

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 10 project with the following dependencies

```
 "@smart-webcomponents-angular/button": "^9.3.43",
 "@smart-webcomponents-angular/calendar": "^9.2.73",
 "@smart-webcomponents-angular/input": "^9.2.73",
 "@smart-webcomponents-angular/scheduler": "^9.2.73",
 "@smart-webcomponents-angular/tree": "^9.2.22",
```

The problem is when I run the project using ng serve it runs with no issue in browser but when I generate a prod build and deploy the project on ApacheTomcat or Weblogic the application component using the above components throws error on console while inspect.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dm92.png)

Please tell me the solution out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the import in the ts file you are using this in. Make sure it is **not** importing from the internal as this is from the module its self

e.g. for rxjs

make sure it is **not** importing from the **internal** location:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
```

instead:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```